# Iterate through nested json and customize it into a new json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

> here is the json data I am getting in output. I need to get the mean of all the values corresponding to their respective keys. Here in this case we have to get the mean value for Years.

```
data = {
    "Weather": [{
            "Calc": [{
                    "Year": 2003,
                    "temp": 45,

                }, {
                    "Year": 2005,
                    "temp": 47,

                }, {
                    "Year": 2008,
                    "temp": 41,

                }
            ],

        }, {

            "Calc": [{
                    "Year": 2003,
                    "temp": 33,

                }, {
                    "Year": 2005,
                    "temp": 38,

                }, {
                    "temp": 36,
                    "Year": 2007,

                }
            ]
        }, {

            "Calc": [{
                    "Year": 2004,
                    "temp": 13,

                }, {
                    "Year": 2005,
                    "temp": 19,

                }, {
                    "Year": 2008,
                    "temp": 21,

                }
            ]
        }, {

            "Calc": [{
                    "Year": 2003,
                    "temp": 20,

                }, {
                    "Year": 2005,
                    "temp": 27,

                }, {
                    "Year": 2008,
                    "temp": 29,

                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

> Now I need to the get the mean of all the values for the same key and customize it into this form -

```
 data= {
   "Weather": [
      {
          "Calc": [
              {
                    "Year": 2003,
                    "temp": 45,

              },
              {
                    "Year": 2005,
                    "temp": 47,

              },
              {
                    "Year": 2008,
                    "temp": 41,

              }
        ]
}
]
```

};

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Well to start with I used 2 nested loops to iterate through them. But the problem comes for identifying the same index every time. As JS arrays are not as easy as PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my approach:

```
//initialise an empty result object.
var result = {};

//iterate through the weather array.
data.Weather.forEach(function(weather){
    //iterate through the contained 'calc' arrays.
    weather.Calc.forEach(function(item){
        //create a new index in the result object for the given year if it doesn't already exist.
        result[item.Year] = result[item.Year] || [];
        //add this temperature to the year.
        result[item.Year].push(item.temp);
    });
});

//we now have an object containing arrays of all the temps under each year

//average them!
for (year in result){
    var avg = 0;
    result[year].forEach(function(val){
        avg += val;
    });
    avg = avg/result[year].length;
    result[year] = avg;
}
```

`console.log(result)` yields:

```
{ 
  2003: 32.666666666666664, 
  2004: 13, 
  2005: 32.75, 
  2007: 36, 
  2008: 30.333333333333332
}
```

Which is fairly trivial to convert into the format in the question.

Comment: If you want to closer inspect how this works, use `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));` before the final `for...in` loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ed.. Your code helped in optimization as my computations (looping) was way longer than yours.

Comment: no probs - please vote up my answer or accept it if you're satisfied :)